# How to call the update the value based on condition by calling recursively or better way in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

I have array of objects `arrobj` , parameter `paramid`

if the `id` is same in the list, then make it value as `null`,

store the previous value `preValue`

then update other object `val` for those preValue > val only.

(values are updated like val, val+1, val+2, val+3 ...)

return arrobj, how to achieve this using javascript

```
example1

let paramid = 28
const arrObj = [
  { id: 10, val: null }, 
  { id: 13, val: 1 }, 
  { id: 14, val: 2 },
  { id: 25, val: 5 },
  { id: 23, val: 8 },
  { id: 43, val: 7 },
  { id: 28, val: 6 },
  { id: 26, val: 10 }
];

In this example, since id and paramid same,  

  val will be null, { id: 28, val: null } preValue = 6

In the list check preValue > val, there are three Objects,  

  { id: 23, val: 8 }, // updated to 7 (preVal+1)
  { id: 43, val: 7 }, // updated to 6 (preVal)
  { id: 26, val: 10 } // updated to 8 (preVal+2)



Expected Output

[
  { id: 10, val: null }, 
  { id: 13, val: 1 }, 
  { id: 14, val: 2 },
  { id: 25, val: 5 },
  { id: 23, val: 7 },
  { id: 43, val: 6 },
  { id: 28, val: null },
  { id: 26, val: 8 }
];

example 2

let paramid = 28
const arrobj = [
  { id: 10, val: null },
  { id: 13, val: 1 },
  { id: 14, val: 2 },
  { id: 25, val: 10 }, 
  { id: 23, val: 6 },
  { id: 43, val: 7 },
  { id: 28, val: 4 }
];


Expected Output

[
  { id: 10, val: null },
  { id: 13, val: 1 },
  { id: 14, val: 2 },
  { id: 25, val: 6 }, 
  { id: 23, val: 4 },
  { id: 43, val: 5 },
  { id: 28, val: null }
];

example 3
paramid = 14
arrobj = [
  { id: 10, val: null },
  { id: 13, val: 1 },
  { id: 14, val: 3 }
  { id: 16, val: 2 }
]

Expected Output

[
  { id: 10, val: null },
  { id: 13, val: 1 },
  { id: 14, val: null }
  { id: 16, val: 2 }
]
```

```
Tried
const getSameId =  arrobj(e=>e.id === paramid);

let oldValue = getSameId.val;

for (let item of arrobj) {
  const index = arrobj.index(item)
  if(item.id === paramid) {
   ...item,
   val: null 
  }
  if(item.id !== paramid && oldValue > item.val) {
   ...item,
   val: oldValue + 1 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary, the code searches for an object in the arrObj array with a specific id value (paramid). If found, it sets the corresponding val property to null and recursively finds the next higher value in the array. It updates the val property of the next higher value and repeats the process until no higher value is found.

```
let paramid = 28
const arrObj = [
    { id: 10, val: null }, 
    { id: 13, val: 1 }, 
    { id: 14, val: 2 },
    { id: 25, val: 5 },
    { id: 23, val: 8 },
    { id: 43, val: 7 },
    { id: 28, val: 6 },
    { id: 26, val: 10 }
];

let increment = 0;
let preVal = 0;
for (let item of arrObj) {
  if(item.id === paramid) {
    preVal = item.val;
    item.val = null;
    findFirstHigherVal(preVal);
  }
}

function findFirstHigherVal(value) {
    let firstObj = undefined;
    for (let item of arrObj) {
        if(item.val > value) {
       

 if(firstObj === undefined || firstObj.val > item.val)
            firstObj = {id: item.id, val: item.val} 
        }
    }
    if(firstObj !== undefined) {
        for (let item of arrObj) {
            if(item.id === firstObj.id) {
                item.val = preVal + increment;
                increment ++;
                break;
            }
        }
        findFirstHigherVal(preVal + increment - 1);
    }
}
```